# All UISteppers that I add to my app appear zoomed at 2x

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios6, uistepper

Recently upgraded to XCode 4.5
I have a screen that's had 2 UIStepper controls on it for quite some time and all of a sudden  they're appearing at twice the size that they should.  Upon further testing, the same problem occurs when I add a UIStepper to any screen on my app.  It appears fine on the StoryBoard but jumps to 2x when the app is run, both on the Device and in the Simulator.  I tried manually setting the frame in viewWillAppear and that didn't fix it.

I created a new single view project to test adding just a UIStepper to the app and it works just fine there.  I also tried copying/pasting the working UIStepper to my real app and it still appeared zoomed to 2x.  Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the line of code that causes the problem:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundImage:imgBtn forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

UIStepper is not a subclass of UIButton, but I'm guessing it uses two UIButtons internally.
This must be a change with iOS6, as this code didn't effect UISteppers in iOS5.

Was able to resolve this by clearing the image from all UISteppers using it's appearance property:

```
[[UIStepper appearance] setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```